# How to always get the same number from a changable number?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, math

i have an array which stores books, and i want to show a **fixed number** of those books, the array length is changable, so how would i always end up with the same number ? based on the length of the array? and increase that number each time a button is clicked ?

how i would want the functionality of my page:

"the shown items is 10, and always 10, and then everytime the button is clicked i would show 10 more, if the last books aren't less than 10, then i would show them

what i want is this:

```
function BooksContainer(){
const itemLength = booksData.length

const [booksShown,setBooksShown] = useState(fixedItemLength)

return (
   booksData.slice(0,booksShown).map(()=>{
      return <Books>
    })

   <button onClick={setBooksShown((prev)=> prev + fixedItemLength)}>Show More</button>)
}
```

writing the question, i think im approaching the problem wrongly, thank you in advance

Comment: Aside: Why are you slicing from the beginning of booksData always?

Comment: because i want the books shown to be increased, so i have to slice from the start of the array

Comment: Ok. Could you clarify or explain differently what you mean by this " if the last books aren't less than 10, then i would show them"?

Comment: Looks like the functionality working well right? I just see that the `onClick` should be a function, not a constant. Try `onClick={() => setBooksShown(....)}`

Comment: will my idea was that i would show only 10, and increase that number, so +10 each click, and if its not i thought it would break, because i would've given the slice function a false value

Comment: @OnurDoğan i did tried it, and yes it works alright, but the only problem is that i can't control the items i show, they could be 50 on a page based on the length of the array, i tried this code ```const booksLength = Math.floor(booksData.length / 2);```

Comment: This is pagination functionality. You are getting it wrong.

Comment: @MurtazaAlkabie slice doesnt care if you go past the actual amount, it will treat it as the upper limit. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> …the shown items is 10, [?], then everytime the button is clicked i would show 10 more, if the last books *aren't* [are ?] less than 10, then i would show them

Since you want to show 10 at the start but increase by 10 upon successive clicks, this should work. It will increase what gets shown (by 10) each time the `button` gets clicked.

*Aside:* Shouldn’t `Books` take a prop? The `booksData` is expected to be an array of `books` or isn’t it? Won’t `Books` take data from this array which it will render? I added that in the code with highlights but you could remove it if you want.

```
function BooksContainer()
{
    let pageSize = 10;
    let start = 0;
    const [end, setEnd] = useState(pageSize - 1);
    return (
        <>
            {
                booksData.slice(start, end).map((book, index) => (
                    <Books book={book} key={index} />
                )
            }
            <button
            disabled={end > booksData.length}
            onClick={
                () => setEnd(prev => prev + pageSize - 1)
            }>Show More</button>
        </>
    )
}
```

*Couldn’t resist to nitpick but it should be `Book` not `Books`.*

Comment: thank you for your answer, i wrote the code above and didn't paste my actual code just so i introudce the problem and not worry about correct code, i see that i made things complicated by thinking the slice could break if the number was higher than the length of the array, so i wanted a dynimac number based on the array length, than you again